# How to test content of html element with qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I have an html element that contains other elements (`a`, `span`) which contain text like "this is a text". As some words are inside `a` or `span` or both the result of jqueries `text()` is something like `"  this\n       is a\n        text             "`. I'm not interested in all those whitespace. I just want to test if "this is a text" is the readable text in the element.

I could workaround this by using regex, e.g. `assert.ok(string.match(/^\s*this\s+is\s+a\s+text\s*^/))` but this is kinda ugly plus I'd loose the "expected: ... , result: ...." stuff in the test report. Is there a better way to test the text contents of html elements with qunit/jquery?

Update:
There seems to be no other way/convenience method in qunit to solve that, except for manually messing with the whitespaces like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27779636/1250436

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

Comment: `trim` would only remove leading and trailing whitespaces, which is clearly not enough for this use.

Comment: You can't get an expected/actual diff without "real" values, so you wouldn't be able to just use the regex as you suggest. That said, do you really want to test the text inside the anchor or span? Do you want your test to fail if it changes to "this is the text"? Why not test for the HTML elements themselves, not the text within?

Comment: @jakerella i want to test if the visible text inside a container (no matter how it is formatted) is equal to a certain text. Capybara has a `contains` method that does exactly that.

Comment: In that case, the only solution I see if you want an actual "diff" is to remove the whitespace and compare that with your expected value as @sadikhasan suggested.

Comment: @jakerella I knew that. The question is, if there is a better way or an existent function. "There isn't" is actually an acceptable answer, but maybe times will change and I will only mark an actual solution to the question as valid answer, not the simple fact that there is currently no other way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that is the current answer... that said, you can always write a [custom assertion](http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#custom-assertions) to handle this. :) I can give it a try if you want to see, but it wouldn't be "built-in".

Comment: @jakerella please don't. I only had a single question, that currently, can't be answered better. 8-)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove extra spaces by following code.

```js
string = " this            is a     text ";
string = string.replace(/[\t\n\s]+/g, " "); //For removing space,tab and new line
alert(string);
```

Comment: So it is not possible to do it without regexes?

Comment: No. It is not possible

Comment: No. I have asked for a solution without doing the regex stuff manually. It is pretty obvious that I can replace all whitespaces with single ones by myself.

Comment: @Sadikhasan you might want to add how he could use that result in a QUnit test.

Comment: No that is not necessary and would actually be even more unrelated to the actual question. I'll add a note that this is currently the only solution to the question.